# Use of [feature-request]

Tags: discussion, meta

We were just having a discussion on the use of meta tags on [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) posts.  Some use [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), while others use [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).  We should have a standard for this, instead of picking tags willy-nilly.

Comment: I think this can also be applied to the [meta-tag:burninate-request] tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd go with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). Not exactly because it's perfectly suited for the job... but because the other three required tags are more clearly incorrect. And it does sort of fit; it'll probably take some community discussion to hash out whether a given synonym is correct or not before anyone takes any action.

Answer (score 9):

The [excerpt of the feature-request tag](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?sort=newest) says:

> You have an idea for a new feature, or for a change to the existing functionality.

I don't think a [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) is either of those.